# How to Add StockItem to list

Tags: c#

I have this code for my test, can  you please help me

1)  A barcode label on a box in our warehouse has the following format
HKGB43563PC5 
The first 3 characters are always the country code, and the last 3 relate to the number of pieces. The value in the middle may vary in length, and may be a combination of letters and numbers in no particular order.

A `List<T>` has already been declared in the main application, you can assume it is accessible from both the class and the method.

```
List<StockItems> stockList = new List<StockItems>();
```

Write code that would replace the comments in the method and the class below to ensure that the list gets populated.

```
Private void AddStockItemToList(string barcode)
 {
   //ToDo Parse the string and add the items to the list.
 }


public class StockItems
{
    public int Quantity;
    public string OriginCountryCode;
    public string StockItemReference
    public Items(int qty, string country, string reference)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something using `substring`. `s.Substring(0, 3);` and `s.Substring(s.Length - 3, 3);` may work. If you are having issues, more than happy to help, but give it a try first

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the `StockItem` class (note that in general a class name should not be plural unless it's a collection) to include a `Parse` method that returns a new `StockItem` based on an input string.

I would also write a helper method to get the actual number of items from the quantity string (assuming that the first part of the quantity is the package code and the last part is the number of "packages"):

```
public class StockItem
{
    public int Quantity;
    public string OriginCountryCode;
    public string StockItemReference;

    public StockItem(int qty, string countryCode, string reference)
    {
        Quantity = qty;
        OriginCountryCode = countryCode;
        StockItemReference = reference;
    }

    public static StockItem Parse(string barcode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode) || barcode.Length < 7)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("barcode argument must be at least 7 characters.");
        }

        return new StockItem(GetNumItems(barcode.Substring(barcode.Length - 3)), 
            barcode.Substring(0, 3), barcode.Substring(3, barcode.Length - 6));
    }

    private static int GetNumItems(string pkgCodeQty)
    {
        if (pkgCodeQty == null || pkgCodeQty.Length != 3)
            throw new ArgumentException("pkgCodeQty string must be 3 characters long");

        // Some kind of dictionary that maps a package code with a count
        var packageCodeMap = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"PC", 1},
            {"PK", 10},
            {"CS", 50},
            {"PL", 100}
        };

        foreach (var pkgMap in packageCodeMap)
        {
            if (pkgCodeQty.StartsWith(pkgMap.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                int qty;

                if (!int.TryParse(pkgCodeQty.Substring(pkgMap.Key.Length), out qty))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        "Package code was not followed by a valid quantity");
                }

                return qty * pkgMap.Value;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown pkgCodeQty type specified");
    }
}
```

Then you can just use this method to create a new `StockItem` and add it to your list:

```
List<StockItem> StockList = new List<StockItem>();

private void AddStockItemToList(string barcode)
{
    StockList.Add(StockItem.Parse(barcode));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. What point are you making here? How can this be improved?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.  Please note for future references that SO is not a place for others to do your homework for you.

```
Private void AddStockItemToList(string barcode)
 {
       string countryCode = barcode.Substring(0, 3);
       string referenceCode = barcode.Substring(barcode.Length - 3);
       stockList.add(new Items(1, countryCode, referenceCode);

 }


public class StockItems
{
    public int Quantity;
    public string OriginCountryCode;
    public string StockItemReference
    public Items(int qty, string country, string reference)
    {
       Quantity = qty;
       OriginCountryCode = country;
       StockItemReference = reference;
    }
}
```